# how to import a txt file in android studio and use it as string?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to work with a text in android studio that is very long(70 pages approximately). first is a way to put in my main activity in android studio code?
OR how can I import it and use it as string?

for example:

```
String deey = "my long text";
```

so I cant use it. I want to add it to my program and use it as string.
I put it into asset folder. but I can't use it.

Comment: Please note your should AsyncTask to perform these action else your main UI block. and check how to read text file in android from asset

Comment: Please note your should AsyncTask to perform these action else your main UI block. and check how to read text file in android from asset

Answer (score 2):

You can get an InputStream from the AssetManager calling the opne() method.

```
   public static String getReadTextFromAssets(Context context, String textFileName) {
        String text;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = context.getAssets().open(textFileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            while ((text = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(text);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Keep your file in the assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in assets and read it using the below function.

```
public String readFromAssets(String fileName, Context context) {
        StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream fIn = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        try {
            fIn = context.getResources().getAssets()
                    .open(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
            input = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                returnString.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (isr != null)
                    isr.close();
                if (fIn != null)
                    fIn.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return returnString.toString();
    }
```

So in your code you will initialise the string as

```
String longString = readFromAssets("helloworld.txt",mContext);
```